# Is there a tooltip tool that works with NuxtJS?

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, nuxt.js

Is there any tooltip tool that is integrated under NuxtJS? Currently I tried to use the v-tooltip but unfortunately I can't use it. Immediately it crashes.

I created the file in the plugins folder named tooltip.js and attached the following code there:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VTooltip from 'v-tooltip'

Vue.use(VTooltip)
```

Then in nuxt.config.js in the plugins object I attached this file.

Error when used:

```js
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                      friendly-errors 11:04:04  


 ERROR  in ./components/Dashboard/Navigation/index.vue?vue&type=template&id=a70e9826&

Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js): friendly-errors 11:04:04  
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)

  Errors compiling template:

  tag <button> has no matching end tag.

  13 |      <div class="user-panel">
  14 |        <div class="notification">
  15 |          <button v-tooltip="'You have new messages.'">
     |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  16 |          <i class="fas fa-envelope">
  17 |            <div v-if="notification_active" class="notification-dot"></div>

                                                                             friendly-errors 11:04:04
 @ ./components/Dashboard/Navigation/index.vue?vue&type=template&id=a70e9826& 1:0-209 1:0-209
 @ ./components/Dashboard/Navigation/index.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./layouts/dashboard.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./layouts/dashboard.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./layouts/dashboard.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=client&path=/__webpack_hmr/client ./.nuxt/client.js
                                                                             friendly-errors 11:04:04  
» Updated components\Dashboard\Navigation\index.vue
```

Comment: Any error logs?

Comment: I was editing the thread

Comment: Did you add the end tag `</button>`?

Comment: I would like to introduce myself to you. I'm an idiot. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Hi Damian, sorry for the sudden message. I was working on the nuxt.js app and I came across the same issue you had before. Have you solved this issue?

I followed the Chris42's advice, but I cannot see the tooltip shown up on my screen yet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For me is ok with create

`plugins/tooltip.js`

```
import Vue from "vue"
import { VTooltip, VPopover, VClosePopover } from "v-tooltip"

Vue.directive("tooltip", VTooltip);
Vue.directive("close-popover", VClosePopover)
Vue.component("v-popover", VPopover)
```

add css https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip#style-examples

And use

```
<input
  type="text"
  value=""
  class="form-control"
  v-tooltip="'Test tooltip'"
/>
```

Comment: This will add `v-tooltip` to vendors and download it as unused code for all the pages

Answer (score 3):

With Nuxt3 you can use [Floating Vue](https://floating-vue.starpad.dev/guide/)

1. yarn add floating-vue
2. Create file `plugins/floating-vue.ts` with below code
3. Enjoy nice tooltip as component or directive :)

**plugins/floating-vue.ts**

```
import FloatingVue from 'floating-vue'
import 'floating-vue/dist/style.css'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(FloatingVue)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use primevue with nuxt 3 and configure tooltip directive in primevue.js (starter : https://github.com/primefaces/primevue-quickstart-nuxt3/tree/main/plugins)

```
import Message from "primevue/message";
import Sidebar from "primevue/sidebar";
import BlockUI from "primevue/blockui";
import Tooltip from 'primevue/tooltip';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(PrimeVue, { ripple: true })
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(ToastService)
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component('Message', Message)
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component('Button', Button)
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component('InputText', InputText)
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component('InputNumber', InputNumber)
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component('Toast', Toast)
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component('Dropdown', Dropdown)
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component('Sidebar',Sidebar)
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component('BlockUI',BlockUI)
    // nuxtApp.vueApp.component('Tooltip', Tooltip)
    nuxtApp.vueApp.directive('tooltip',   Tooltip)
    //other components that you need
})
```